# Find min and max rotation of a set of points described by non-linear equations

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, maxima-minima, rotations

Let me explain the problem. I have two different reference frames in a 3D space, one is the world origin and the other could be called as top frame.

The data:

- The relation between both frames position (as x, y, z) and orientation (as yaw, pitch, roll) in reference world. I called this variable $P = (x, y, z, yaw, pitch, roll)^T$
- The point $a = (a_x, a_y, a_z)^T$ with reference top.
- The point $b = (b_x, b_y, b_z)^T$ with reference origin.

The restriction:

- The vector magnitude between a and b must be in the range $(v_{min}, v_{max}) \in \mathbb{R}$.

So **I would like to know the range from the point P** (where the top frame was sitting) for each position direction and orientation rotation individually. Let me present what I have been doing for position, which works more or less fine.

The vector can be defined as:

$v = R \cdot a + (P_x, P_y, P_z)^T - b $

Where R is the rotation matrix:

$R = \begin{bmatrix}
        \cos\alpha\cos\beta &
          \cos\alpha\sin\beta\sin\gamma - \sin\alpha\cos\gamma &
          \cos\alpha\sin\beta\cos\gamma + \sin\alpha\sin\gamma \\
        \sin\alpha\cos\beta &
          \sin\alpha\sin\beta\sin\gamma + \cos\alpha\cos\gamma &
          \sin\alpha\sin\beta\cos\gamma - \cos\alpha\sin\gamma \\
       -\sin\beta & \cos\beta\sin\gamma & \cos\beta\cos\gamma \\
  \end{bmatrix}$

And where $\alpha$, $\beta$ and $\gamma$ are yaw, pitch and roll respectly.

For example, the case of x direction I took:

$\Delta x = \pm\sqrt{v^2_{max} - (\|v\|^2 - v^2_x)} - v_x$

or

$\Delta x = \pm\sqrt{v^2_{min} - (\|v\|^2 - v^2_x)} - v_x$

And so on for y and z, but when it comes to the rotations, I am not able to get that range analytically... For now, I have been able to obtain the result by using Newton–Raphson iterative method but I would like to get it like the position because it's much faster computationally.

Let me know if I need to explain me better or if I need to provide anything else. Thanks in advance.

Lluis